# Angular2-webpack-starter kit and SCSS support

Tags: angular, webpack

I have a master scss files with imports to all my seconday scss files. I am trying to get this scss included in my component. I followed the [How to include SCSS in components](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components) but just get errors. If I do all the steps I get this error:

> ERROR in ./src/styles/os_theme.scss
>
> Module build failed:
>
> // Loosely based on https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/
>
> ^
>
> ```
> Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
>   in D:\project\src\styles\os_theme.scss (line 1, column 1)
> ```

That is the comment that is at the beginning of my main scss.

If I remove this part of the webpack.common.js:

```
   {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
    }
```

I get no error when the dev server runs and oddly enough my footer gets the styles I would expect but the rest of the app does not run and in the console I have this error:

> Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.

Here is what my component looks like. app.component.ts

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styleUrls: ['../../src/styles/os_theme.scss'],
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
 })
```

folder structure is:

```
-src
--styles
--- os_theme.scss (as imports to my other files)
--- _general.scss
--- components
----_components.buttons.scss
- app
-- app.component.ts
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that guides is deprecated but you can check the [commit](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/commit/fa823c2ac46b2d87cf591937c8799b193bd5f216) and [app.module.ts](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts#L32-L33) file to check how they have used `scss` and `css` files.

Comment: Thanks I should have picked up on that when I removed those files to try the wiki approach. This is all a bit new to me but why the import statements instead of using Angular2's styleUrls?

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/pull/1304) is an explanation why they've done that. 
To save you a click, the main CSS file is not nested in JS anymore and gets generated in a separate file to provide a smoother UX on the first load.